# how to use user32.dll to change external window title

Tags: c, user32

what i'm trying to do:
i have source code of old game that built in `c`,
and i want that this game process will change the title of external winform application,
something like:

```
int Handle;

    //Find The WinForm Window Handle
    UseLibFunction("user32.dll","FindWindow","My_WinForm_Window_Title",Handle)

    //Change The Title
    UseLibFunction("user32.dll","SendMessage","WM_SETTEXT","New Title",Handle)
```

since i'm not a good programmer  in `C` i can't create kind of global function such as "`UseLibFunction`" (use `UseLibFunction` function **anytime and in any c file that i want** - kind of global function , something like : `include("thefunction.c")`)
another thing: i don't have any c function named: `UseLibFunction` which means that i need to create this function but i have no idea from where to start.
so:
since it's the first and the last c project that i'm going to create:
someone can give me example to **how to use the user32.dll functions by c?**

Comment: You'll need to use a windows SDK or the latest version of mingw64, include `<windows.h>` and link with either `user32.lib` or `user32.so` depending on compiler.

Comment: i'm using borland 3.1

Comment: I would highly suggest using a more modern compiler like [MinGW64](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) which comes with its own windows SDK and is C11 compliant.

Comment: thanks about your comments, i alredy tried this compiler but when i'm runing the compiled exe there is no window creation , i also tried dosbox, the only compiler that compiled it successfully is borland 3.1 , if you have any idea how to make this project easier let me know =)

Comment: I would start [with the tutorials on modern window programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use mingw64 as the compiler.

Comment: thanks, i will try it (remind me dll injection)